# Is it acceptable to omit "about" in this sentence? "I love everything (about) math."

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction

I have two sentences:

> - I love everything about math.
> - I love everything math.

I am [pretty confident](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everything+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceverything%20about%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ceverything%20about%3B%2Cc0) based on the phrase's usage that the first sentence is grammatically correct.

Is it acceptable to omit "about" in the first sentence (thus creating the second sentence)?

Comment: Note that “math” is American English. In British, and other international English, the word is maths with an s on the end. It’s short for “mathematics”.

Comment: I love everything math**ematical**.

Comment: I'll note, when people are speaking loosely like this, I (Mid-Atlantic American English speaker) usually hear it as "I love all things math!", rather than "everything".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is borderline acceptable.

You would normally expect an adjective:  "I love everything spicy".

Now, "math" isn't an adjective, it is a noun. It can be used attributively "a math equation, a math book"  and there is enough flexibility in English to allow for "I love everything math" to be used in a casual way.  It could be used as a personal slogan, for example.

It's certainly not formal enough for a resumé or application letter.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! May I ask why we expect an adjective?

Comment: We have a post-modifier of "everything".  That calls for an adjective.  I don't know of any logical reason for this except "grammar".

Comment: It's an ellipsis for "everything [which is] spicy".

Comment: *I love everything **to do with, about, concerning** maths*, or  *...everything **maths-related*** are alternatives that more explicitly modify ***maths*** using an ***adjectival*** element.

Answer (score 39):

The form "Everything + noun" is a recognized form, often used in the context of marketing, meaning everything that has a connection to whatever the noun is. A shop might advertise itself as for "Everything Football", meaning that they sell anything that has a connection to football; or a website might describe itself as for 'Everything Music', meaning that it relates to everything that is music-related or has a strong musical aspect to it.

So, your phrases have slightly different ranges of meaning:

> I love everything about math.

The most obvious meaning of this that you love every aspect of mathematics. In certain contexts it *could* also mean that you love all works (such as books or films) that have mathematics as their subject.

> I love everything math

This means that you love everything that has a mathematical aspect to it. Perhaps you have Fermat's conjecture tattooed on your back, or your bedsheets have the Fibonacci sequence printed on them? And again, it could also mean that you mean works (such as books or films) that have mathematics as their subject.

*In summary:* "I love everything about math" is a straightforward and standard sentence stating primarily that you love every aspect of mathematics. "I love everything math" is a more informal, slightly marketing-flavored sentence that highlights your love of things with a connection to mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for, “I like everything mathematical.”  The construction should have an adjective that means “about math.”

Answer (score 3):

I might say "I love everything math" in an informal context, like on social media, or if I were writing a funny essay.  I would immediately follow it with examples to make my meaning clear.  For example, "I love everything math:  The sexy, smooth normal curve, the consistent way 2+3=5 day after day after day, the thrill of knowing that 7 * 5 = 35 / 7 always takes you back to 5, and even the very shapes of the numbers."

But if I were writing an essay in a formal setting like a job application or a college entrance essay, I would use "I love everything about math".